# How can I make a restart command for my discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working on making a bot, and one of the things I came across is that it would be nice to have a restart command, but I don't know how. Also, I want to make it so only I can shut it down, not other people. Here is my Discord ID so you can put that into the code: `717485854423253154`

All help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. I'm afraid this is a site for helping you write _your own_ code, so I suggest you find yourself a good python tutorial, and after that a discord tutorial. When you get stuck, come back with the specific problem -- and the best code you've managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```py
@bot.command()
async def shutdown(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.id != 717485854423253154: return
    try:
        await self.bot.logout()
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        print(e)
        self.bot.clear()
```